# Does expo, problem with webview, it show page blank screen

Tags: react-native, expo

currency I am working with React Native and expo, yesterday I was working with WebView however my project it show blanck screen, when I compile my project, I see everything through of my phone, I already tried everything to solve it but I have not been successful, **somebody can I help me plese?, i don't know what to do.**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
 },
});

export default function App(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <Text>Test text</Text>
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: 'https://www.youtube.com' }}
    />
    </View>
   );
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo start --android",
  "ios": "expo start --ios",
  "web": "expo start --web",
  "eject": "expo eject"
},
"dependencies": {
  "expo": "~41.0.1",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "17.0.2",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
  "react-native-web": "~0.16.3",
  "react-native-webview": "11.2.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.14.3"
},
"private": true
```

Answer (score 0):

Having this issue as well, I noticed if I use the example on the github docs it will load a video, but so far not able to render html or a webpage:

<WebView source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/' }} />

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this into Snack.expo.io

I am a little unclear as to what exactly your problem is but this renders the webpage fine on both android and iphones.

The issue that causes the white screen is the styling. If you remove the styling besides flex: 1, it renders completely.

```
export default function App(){
  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: 'https://www.youtube.com' }}
    />
   );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it's the same as i have in my code

Comment: Which tells you that its probably in your styling, I would try and start over with what I gave you, and style it from there while making sure after each chance it still works. You should also make what your problem is a little more clear.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I not clean because i don't speak english I learning still, but i will do what you say and thank again